# Can I go directly to a Newest Question Page?

Tags: feature-request

I'm going through the site backwards by page. I've got it set to 50 questions per page to make it as quick as I know how if I somehow lose my place, but it is still frustrating. Sometimes I'll follow a link and I can't get back, once I lost power, a few times I've just been dumb. Is there a way to go straight to Newest Questions - Page 138? Or do I have to keep clicking, move to the bottom of the page, click again...repeat...repeat...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit the URL:

[https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions?page=**100**&sort=newest](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions?page=100&sort=newest)

Comment: Yay! Thanks, that sounds a lot less frustrating.